# definining $message="" variable

Tags: php

this code all works fine except for I get an undefined variable warning 'message' and I cant figure out a way to define it as it is not a post or session variable or anything that. Thanks

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
  $repeatnewemail = $_POST['repeatnewemail'];
  $email= ($_SESSION['email']);
  $message="";

 //open database

  if (condition)
  {
    $message="first message";
  }
}

?>

<p td class='td2'><?php echo $message;?></td>
```

Answer (score 6):

Put the  `$message="";` outside the condition.

```
$message="";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
    $repeatnewemail = $_POST['repeatnewemail'];
    $email= ($_SESSION['email']);


 //open database


    if (condition){
        $message="first message";
    }
}

?>
<p td class='td2'><?php echo $message;?></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

declare $message on top  :-

```
$message = ""
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
 $repeatnewemail = $_POST['repeatnewemail'];
 $email= ($_SESSION['email']);

 //open database


 if (condition)
 {
  $message="first message";
 }
}

?>
 <p td class='td2'><?php if(isset($message)) echo $message;?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$message=null;
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
 $repeatnewemail = $_POST['repeatnewemail'];
 $email= ($_SESSION['email']);
 $message="";

 //open database


 if (condition)
 {
  $message="first message";
 }
}

?>
 <p td class='td2'><?php if(isset($message)) echo $message;?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you have not defined $message.

```
$message = ""
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
 $repeatnewemail = $_POST['repeatnewemail'];
 $email= ($_SESSION['email']);

 //open database


 if (condition)
 {
  $message="first message";
 }
}

?>
 <p td class='td2'><?php if(isset($message)) echo $message;?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `$message=""` before `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { }` block